# Posted an answer to an on-hold question

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, answers, questions

[This](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/42167/14704) question has been put on hold at 18:36 server time. I have posted an answer to it at 18:59 server time. Which should not be possible.

I have started writing an answer when the question was still open. My guess is, the system checked whether or not an answer may be posted when it let me to start answering, rather than when I've finished writing and clicked "post".

It's not the system's intended behaviour, is it?

Comment: I've had this happen before a couple of times, where a question was closed while I was writing an answer but I was still able to submit it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That actually is intended behavior.  Think about how aggravating it would be to spend half an hour writing a long, thorough answer with plenty of examples and external links and whatnot, only to get told "bzzt! five minutes too late, bye!" when you click "post".  Instead, the server allows a grace period (I think of an hour) for answers that were *already in progress* when the question gets put on hold.  With luck, whatever caused it to be put on hold can be resolved quickly, the question gets reopened, and your answer is joined by others.

Comment: Clarification: [it's 4 hours](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/91928/241919) and only disables the button, but users can manually enable it using dev tools to post after the question has been closed before the 4-hour threshold.